# Why can't openstack's virtual machine unbind/detach PCI devices such as GPU?

Tags: gpu, virtual-machine, openstack, pci

Why can't openstack's virtual machine unbind/detach PCI devices such as GPU?

After I created a virtual machine in openstack using flavor with GPU device, the virtual machine cannot unbind/detach this GPU. This makes me very confused and I hope to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

- 1, create a new flavor which copy from the original flavor used to create server but without the **property** like `"resources:VGPU"`.
- 2, resize the original server to the new flavor.

Or remove GPU by [virsh](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_virtualization/assembly_managing-gpu-devices-in-virtual-machines_configuring-and-managing-virtualization) the section of **Removing NVIDIA vGPU devices**.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But I just tried to use ```resize```. The situation is as follows:
1. If both virtual machines do not have GPU, ```resize``` can succeed.
2. If a virtual machine has a GPU and the resized ```flavor``` does not have a GPU, an error is reported: ```no valid host was fund No valid host found for resize.```       

At the same time, it should be noted that in my environment, a GPU is directly pass-through the virtual machine.

Comment: @skyzk could you try to detach the GPU in host?

Comment: Until now, I can't. However, the virtual machine I created through virt-manager can successfully unbind GPU through the command: ```virsh detach device```.

Comment: And if I create a new virtual machine through ```flavor``` in openstack, I can't unbind GPU through the command: ```virsh detach-device```.